# why might my pyglet vertex lists and batches be very slow on Windows?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I'm writing opengl code in python using the library pyglet. When I draw to the screen using pyglet.graphics.vertex_list or pyglet.graphics.batch objects, they are very slow (~0.1 fps) compared to plain old pyglet.graphics.draw() or just glVertex() calls, which are about 40fps for the same geometry.
In Linux the vertex_list is about the same speed as glVertex, which is disappointing, and batch methods are about twice as fast, which is a little better but not as much gain as I was hoping for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to invoke your pyglet scripts with 'python -O myscript.py', the '-O' flag can make a huge performance difference.

See pyglet docs [here](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/gl.html?highlight=performance#error-checking) and [here](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/options.html?highlight=debug_gl).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know personally, but I noticed that you haven't posted to [the pyglet mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/pyglet-users) about this. More Pyglet users, as well as the primary developer, read that list.